# URL parameters disappears(removed) after changing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

As the video shows, the changed url parameter disappears(cleaned/removed) after changing.

> https://youtu.be/06aHXdNl7J8

For example, when I choose Taipei in the dropdown, the url should be

> http://localhost:3003/user/quick_search/index?departure_name=TAIPEI

But it only persists for a short time,

Then it returned to the original url `http://localhost:3003/user/quick_search/index`

For my use case, the parameters are multiple and optional, I'm doing the 2-way binding of `URL parameters` and `FORM control`

## update

For example, If I choose  `CHIANGMAI` as the departure, it seems working at first. The url will be `http://133.130.101.114:3000/user/quick_search/index#/?departure_name=CHIANGMAI`

However, it will quickly revert to  `http://133.130.101.114:3000/user/quick_search/index#/`

This is the demo site `http://133.130.101.114:3000/user/quick_search/index#/`

## App config

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function(routeProvider, locationProvider) {
  routeProvider.
    when('/',
      {
        templateUrl: 'quick_search/form.html',
        controller: 'form_ctrl'
      }
    ).
    otherwise(
      {
        templateUrl: 'quick_search/form.html',
        controller: 'form_ctrl'
      }
    );

  locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
  });

}]);
```

## Form_Controller.js (#change URL params after changing dropdown option)

```
  $scope.updateDeparture = function(departure){
    if ( ! (typeof departure === 'undefined' || departure === null) ){
      $scope.departure_name = departure.name;
    }
  }

  $scope.$watch("departure_name", function(newValue) {
      $location.search("departure_name", newValue);
  });
```

Comment: you have an error and a _WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once._ in the console. Why don't you check them first?

Comment: Hi I fixed it, but the problem still remains.